# React: Is there a way that the Parent gets a variable from a Child component without onSubmit, onChange or similar events?

Tags: reactjs

```
export default function Child(props: any) {
    ...

    const isHidden: boolean = ...;
    ...
    ...
}

export default function Parent(props: any) {
    const {children} = props;

    return (
            <>
                {children}
            </>
           )
}
```

Is there a way to pass `isHidden` to the `Parent` component without `onSubmit`, `onChange` or similar events that need to be triggered manually? I need when the `Parent` renders just to get this variable from its `Child`.

In fact `children` are passed to the `Parent` and I need to check whether this variable exists in each child. If it exists I need to get its value.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

Answer (score 1):

isHidden should be a state and you should lift the state up and pass it with props

for example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [childs, setChilds] = useState([
    { isHidden: true },
    { isHidden: false },
    { isHidden: true },
  ]);

  return (
    <Parent childs={chlids}>
      {childs.map((child) => (
        <Child isHidden={child.isHidden} />
      ))}
    </Parent>
  );
};
```